# acerca de bootstrap y codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, bootstrap-3

tengo una duda con bootstrap mire ya vengo de hacer un proyecto con codeigniter y bootstrap  el problema q tengo es q no me reconoce el bootstrap a la hora de ejecutar

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-aUGj/X2zp5rLCbBxumKTCw2Z50WgIr1vs/PFN4praOTvYXWlVyh2UtNUU0KAUhAX" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0rc1.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= base_url() ?>plantilla/css/home.css">


<title> <?= $title ?></title>

</head>

<body>
```

aca esta el codigo de la vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: la ubicacion de booststrap coinside?

Comment: estoy usando el cdn de bootstrap                                                              <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">                                                                         <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">                                                          <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: ¿En la pestaña consola no te muestra algún error?

Answer (score 1):

Bueno que muestres el error que te da la consola seria de mas ayuda. Pero viendo lo que tienes allí, veo que están al revés las declaraciones de bootstrap y jquery.

Boostrap tiene como dependencia Jquery, por tanto jquery debería estar antes que bootstrap.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0rc1.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: lo probare aunq hace rato igual cambie de lugar y no salia nada ahora estoy probando descargando bootstrap gracias la imagen q postee me salia vcuando revisaba elementos me salia tachado como si no reconociera